# VBA Loop with Cell Values

Tags: excel, vba

I am pretty new to vba and I am facing a problem I couldn't find a solution to so far. I have two lists of names in the worksheet "Source" that I want to use for a for each loop. How can I address those cells by using the correct Worksheet?

I want to access combo boxes that are named "Box*variablename*" (e.g. BoxIAA) and associated text boxes in the form "*variablename*value" (e.g. IAAvalue) and check the content of all these objects, deleting the two cells to the right (e.g. D3:E3 or G5:H5) in the worksheet "Source" if the objects are empty.

My attempt was:

```
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range(Sheets("Source").Range("C2:C4"), Sheets("Source").Range("F2:F5"))


For Each cell In rng
    If "Box" & cell.Value <> "" Then

        MsgBox "The value is " & "Box" & Range(cell).Value

    Else If
        'Delete two cells to the right in ws "Source"
    End If  

Next cell
```

I am aware, that I am not addressing the Cells C2:C4 in the worksheet Source correctly, but I really don't know how to do it properly.
How can I access the content of the source cells and address the content / the cells for later use?

Comment: Note that the `Range` in `Set rng = Range(` is not itself qualified by the worksheet. In order to save on typing, why not declare and set a worksheet variable `ws`? Also, if `cell` is a range object then `Range(cell)` is pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying (**untested**)?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim aCell As Range

    On Error GoTo Whoa '<~~ Need this in case it couldn't find the control

    Set rng = Sheets("Source").Range("C2:C4,F2:F5")

    For Each aCell In rng
        '~~> Use Controls() to work with the control
        With Me.Controls("Box" & aCell.Value)
            If .Value <> "" Then
                MsgBox .Value
            Else
                '~~> Do what you want
                Sheets("Source").Range(aCell.Offset(, 1), _
                                       aCell.Offset(, 2)).Delete shift:=xlLeft
            End If
        End With
    Next aCell

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Instead of `If .Value <> "" Then` you can also use `If .ListIndex <> -1 Then`. I am assuming that there are no blank values in the combobox.

Comment: Thank you so much Siddharth Rout, that solved the issue! I really had no plan on how to solve it! Works great